# Create column in GeoDataFrame and write new value to it

Tags: python, gis, geopandas

I am trying to add a column to a shapefile read in as a GeoDataFrame and populate that column with a simple count derived from a point dataset. When I do this, the column is filled with NaN which leads me to believe it is a series that needs to be referenced with iloc as opposed to a scalar.

```
polys["conflict"] = None
for index, row in polys.iterrows():
    polygon = polys.geometry[0]
    subset = conflict[conflict.within(polygon)]
    scalar = subset.iloc[0]
    polys = polys.assign(conflict=subset)
```

polys is a gdf (polygons). conflict is a point dataset also read in as a gdf.

Also tried:

```
polys.conflict.iloc[0] = subset
```

Getting an 'Incompatible indexer with DataFrame' error

Answer (score 1):

I tried to follow your code and if I'm not mistaken, you might achieve what you intend to do by making some slight changes:

```
polys["conflict"] = None
for index, row in polys.iterrows():
    polygon = row.geometry
    subset = conflict[conflict.within(polygon)].shape[0] # gets the count of conflict points inside the polygon
    row['conflict'] = subset
```

Another more efficient way to do what you want to do is using the spatial index provided in the `geopandas`' `GeoDataFrame` (full explanation on this available [here](https://geoffboeing.com/2016/10/r-tree-spatial-index-python/)):

```
polys["conflict"] = None

conflict_sindex = conflict.sindex
for index, row in polys.iterrows():
    possible_matches_index = list(conflict_sindex.intersection(row.geometry.bounds))
    possible_matches = conflict.iloc[possible_matches_index]
    precise_matches = possible_matches[possible_matches.intersects(row.geometry)]
    if not precise_matches.empty:
        res = precise_matches.shape[0] # gets the count of conflict points inside the polygon
        row['conflict'] = res
```

Comment: LeandroOrdonez, In both cases, the values for Conflict still result in 'None' for every polygon. There is no value being written back to that column that was created.

Comment: Then you might have to check if there is actually intersection between the `polys` and `conflict` geo-dataframes, and if you are using the same coordinate reference systems (CRS) when reading them in.

You can ensure that by running the following two lines of code after loading both datasets: `polys = polys.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3857'})`, `conflict = conflict.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3857'})`

Comment: The Conflict file did not have a project. I have verified that the Polys file is epsg:4326 and assigned this projection to the Conflict file upon reading it in per the following: conflict.crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}

There absolutely is overlap in the conflict points and polys as I am plotting it natively in Python and can see it and writing it out to shapefiles that show the overlap in QGIS as well.

Still, the conflict column comes up None for all polys.

Comment: I have done something similar I think, and it worked. You can have a look at it [here](https://gist.github.com/LeandroOrdonez/d246edc1457554c580350e35df986469#file-point_in_polygon-ipynb)

Comment: `iterrows` creates a copy of each row. You need to assign the values you're processing using `polys.at[index, 'conflict']` https://thispointer.com/pandas-6-different-ways-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-update-while-iterating-row-by-row/